# Show Char* buffer (Bitmap) in Qt

Tags: image, qt, sockets, char

i receive BItmap image  from socket  so it is char*
i can write  it to file 
but  how  show it directly from buffer

```
ui->label->setPixmap(????)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct QImage from this data and then create QPixmap from it. For example:

```
int dataSize = 1024;
uchar data[dataSize];
QImage image = QImage::fromData(data, dataSize, "PNG");
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
```

Comment: in QImage image(data, dataSize, "PNG");/// cannot convert parameter 1 from 'uchar [10]' to 'int'

Answer (score 1):

```
QByteArray byte=QByteArray::fromRawData(buf, sizeofimagebuffer );
    QPixmap  image;
    if(image.loadFromData(byte,"BMP"))
    {
        ui->label->setPixmap(image);
        ui->label->update();
    }
```

it  work :)